# How to look for strings in array using regex with MongoDB.?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have several objects like this:

```
"status": "published",
"term_id": [
   "anime",
   "sci-fi",
   "etc"
],
"captionCert": "1",
```

I know that in order to look within a single field, I would create something like this:

```
if (keyword) {
  query.status = { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' };
}
```

Where keyword comes from the front end and can be whatever the user types; then I proceed to look into the field status and then I just retrieve it by passing it into my model query:

```
Video.find(query)
```

Now hte problem is that I need to know how to exactly do this but inside the term_id array?

Any idea? Thanks.

UPDATE: I'm trying to implement it into this function:

```
exports.searchVideos = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const query = {};
  const { keyword } = req.query;

  if (keyword) {
    query.title = { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' };
  } else {
    query.text = { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' };
  }

  if (keyword) {
    query.term_id = { term_id: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } };
  };

  const video = await Video.find(query).select(
    'title text thumbnail video_url term_id'
  );
  console.log(query);
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: video });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution after finding out about $or operator. This solved my problems!:

```
exports.searchVideos = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let query = {};
  const { keyword } = req.query;

  query = {
    $or: [
      { title: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } },
      { text: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } },
      { term_id: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' }}
    ]
  };

  const video = await Video.find(query).select(
    'title text thumbnail video_url term_id'
  );

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: video });
});
```